# Is "appelle" in "peut-être que j’appelle..." subjunctive?

Tags: subjonctif

The question is on the highlighted clause in this passage from La porte étroite by André Gide.

> Ta dernière lettre, adressée au Havre, m’écrivit Alissa, est arrivée lorsque nous venions d’en partir. Comment expliquer qu’elle ne m’ait rejointe ici que huit jours après ? Toute la semaine j’ai eu une âme incomplète, transie, douteuse, diminuée. Ô mon frère ! je ne suis vraiment moi, plus que moi, qu’avec toi…
>        
>   Juliette va de nouveau bien ; nous attendons sa délivrance d’un jour à l’autre, et sans trop d’inquiétude. Elle sait que je t’écris ce matin ; le lendemain de notre arrivée à Aigues-Vives elle m’a demandé : – Et Jérôme, que devient-il… Il t’écrit toujours ?… et comme je n’ai pu lui mentir : Quand tu lui écriras, dis-lui que… elle a hésité un instant, puis, en souriant très doucement :… je suis guérie. – Je craignais un peu, dans ses lettres toujours gaies, qu’elle ne me jouât la comédie du bonheur et qu’elle-même ne s’y laissât prendre… Ce dont elle fait son bonheur aujourd’hui reste si différent de ce qu’elle rêvait et dont il semblait que son bonheur dût dépendre… Ah ! que ce qu’on appelle bonheur est chose peu étrangère à l’âme et que les éléments qui semblent le composer du dehors importent peu ! Je t’épargne quantité de réflexions que j’ai pu faire dans mes promenades solitaires sur la garrigue, où ce qui m’étonne le plus c’est de ne pas me sentir plus joyeuse ; le bonheur de Juliette devrait me combler… pourquoi mon cœur cède-t-il à une mélancolie incompréhensible, dont je ne parviens pas à me défendre ? La beauté même de ce pays, que je sens, que je constate du moins, ajoute encore à mon inexplicable tristesse… Quand tu m’écrivais d’Italie, je savais voir à travers toi toute chose ; à présent il me semble que je te dérobe tout ce que je regarde sans toi. Enfin, je m’étais fait, à Fongueusemare et au Havre, une vertu de résistance à l’usage des jours de pluie ; ici cette vertu n’est plus de mise, et je reste inquiète de la sentir sans emploi. Le rire des gens et du pays m’offusque ; **peut-être que j’appelle « être triste » simplement n’être pas aussi bruyant qu’eux…** Sans doute, auparavant, il entrait quelque orgueil dans ma joie, car, à présent, parmi cette gaieté étrangère, c’est quelque chose comme de l’humiliation que j’éprouve.

**QUESTIONS**

1. Is *appelle* in the subjunctive?
2. If yes to 1, then would removing *que* put *appelle* in the indicative?
3. If yes to 1, how does putting the verb in the subjunctive change the meaning or nuance of the clause?
4. If no to 1, what is the contribution of *que* to the overall meaning or nuance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Appelle* is at the present tense in *peut-être que j'appelle* (may be do I call…)

In written and non colloquial French, an [inversion verb/subject is required](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3472) after *peut-être*, e.g.:

> *Peut-être **dit-il** la vérité*
>
> *Peut-être **veux-tu** encore du café*
>
> *Peut-être **dois-je** lui demander*

Following that rule, that sentence might have been written:

> *Peut-être **appelé-je** « être triste » simplement n'être…*

There is however a phonetic issue when an inversion is made with the pronoun ***je*** which leads most verbs to never be used that way.

Gide simply choose to insert *que* which removes the inversion requirement but doesn't reduce the level of language:

> *Peut-être **que j'appelle** « être triste » simplement n'être pas aussi bruyant qu'eux.*

Here is a couple of examples showing *peut-être que* occurrences in French literature and an inversion:

> *Je n'ai reçu que deux de vos lettres; **peut-être que** la troisième viendra;*
>  Marquise de Sévigné
>
> ***Peut-être que** si Jacques savait cela, il agirait autrement; **peut-être aurais-je dû** le lui dire;*
> George Sand

In colloquial spoken French, the sentence might have been:

> *Peut-être **que ce que j'appelle** « être triste », c'est simplement [ne] pas être aussi bruyant qu'eux.*

Answer (score 3):

1:  No, *appelle* is in present indicative tense.

4:  "*Que*" isn't always followed by a subjunctive. "*Peut-être*" is followed by "*que*" in the form : "*peut-être que [affirmation]* "

Both those sentences are equivalent :

> Il est peut-être parti.
>
> Peut-être **qu'il** est parti.

The second form is more casual, it feels more natural for an oral conversation (and the whole text is written in the style of an oral conversation, like someone talking to himself)